# Relationship between convex sets and exact first order differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I think I know what a convex set is, which is that given two points from the set the line formed between them is also in the set. And then there is another type of sets, which I don't know the correct term in english, so I'll just name them "star" sets, which are sets that have a center, and given a random point of a star set, the line between that point and its center is also contained in a the star set. Thus, all convex sets are star sets but not all star sets are convex.

But say I have the folowing differential equation:
$$
A(x,y)+B(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx}=0
$$
Let U be a star set:
$$
A:U\to  I\!R  
$$
$$B:U\to I\!R$$

and 
$$ \begin{equation}
\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}
\end{equation}
$$

Then the differential equation is exact. Now my question is, I thought that if the last condition was met, it automaticaly implied that the differential equation was exact, what is the need of stating that U is a star set?

Please explain in layman terms, because I have looked for a reason for this but the mathematical language is just so overwhelming I get lost in it.

Comment: "Star set" is more-or-less the correct term in English, see here: [Wikipedia page for "star domain"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain).

Comment: That's much better, I was searching "starred set" in google. I was not getting good results.

Answer (score 0):

In a convex set, or a star set, then if you have smooth functions $A$, $B$
with $$\newcommand{\p}{\partial}\frac{\p A}{\p y}=\frac{\p B}{\p x}\tag{1}$$ then there
is a smooth $C$ such that
$$A=\frac{\p C}{\p x}\qquad\text{and}\qquad B=\frac{\p C}{\p y}.\tag{2}$$
Therefore both these notions of "exactness" coincide.

This is not the case for general open sets. If $U=\Bbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$
take
$$A=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad B=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$
then $(1)$ holds, but there is no $C$ such that $(2)$ holds.

Comment: You might mention that the two notions are more properly known as "closed" and "exact"; you might also give a hint _why_ that example is  not exact. (If $(A,B)$ is exact then the integral of $(A,B)$ over any closed curve vanishes, but in that example the integral over the unit circle is non-zero.)

Comment: But why isn't there any C that holds (2)?

Comment: There is also what David mentioned, I don't quite get the distinction between "closed" and "exact", I thought that exact differential equations were called "exact" because what is on the left hand of the equation is the exact derivative of some potential function, and that was it. No more terms. Then, the "closed" term came, with all these sets. Now I'm just lost, "lost in translation"